# R function does not return anything when 'else' clause is evaluated

Tags: r, return

I have a function that takes a list as an input. Here is the code for the function:

```
processAndJoinTables <- function(d_f){

x.log <- d_f$log
x.sale <- d_f$sales
x.disposition <- d_f$disposition
x.disposition <- column.checker(x.disposition)

if(ncol(x.disposition) != 0){

df <- data.frame(time = character(0), user = character(0), user_disposition = character(0), stringsAsFactors = F)

for(i in 1:nrow(x.disposition)){

  df[i, 'time'] <- x.disposition$last_dialed_time[i] %>% as.character()
  df[i+nrow(x.disposition), 'time'] <- x.disposition$last_dialed_time_1[i]  %>% as.character()
  df[i+(2*nrow(x.disposition)), 'time'] <- x.disposition$last_dialed_time_2[i]  %>% as.character()
  df[i+(3*nrow(x.disposition)), 'time']  <- x.disposition$last_dialed_time_3[i]  %>% as.character()
  df[i+(4*nrow(x.disposition)), 'time']  <- x.disposition$last_dialed_time_4[i]  %>% as.character()

  df[i, 'user'] <- x.disposition$last_user_id[i] %>% as.character()
  df[i+nrow(x.disposition), 'user'] <- x.disposition$last_user_id_1[i]  %>% as.character()
  df[i+(2*nrow(x.disposition)), 'user'] <- x.disposition$last_user_id_2[i]  %>% as.character()
  df[i+(3*nrow(x.disposition)), 'user']  <- x.disposition$last_user_id_3[i]  %>% as.character()
  df[i+(4*nrow(x.disposition)), 'user']  <- x.disposition$last_user_id_4[i]  %>% as.character()

  df[i, 'user_disposition'] <- x.disposition$last_attempted_user_disposition[i] %>% as.character()
  df[i+nrow(x.disposition), 'user_disposition'] <- x.disposition$last_disposition_1[i]  %>% as.character()
  df[i+(2*nrow(x.disposition)), 'user_disposition'] <- x.disposition$last_disposition_2[i]  %>% as.character()
  df[i+(3*nrow(x.disposition)), 'user_disposition']  <- x.disposition$last_disposition_3[i]  %>% as.character()
  df[i+(4*nrow(x.disposition)), 'user_disposition']  <- x.disposition$last_disposition_4[i]  %>% as.character()

}

new <- left_join(x.log, df, by = c('date_added' = 'time'))
new <- new[order(new$call_id),]

if(length(which(x.sale$transaction_status == 'PAYMENT_DONE')) != 0) {

  payment_date <- x.sale %>% filter(transaction_status == 'PAYMENT_DONE') %>% select(added_date) %>% as.character() %>% as.POSIXct()

  saleAttemptCalls <- left_join(new %>% filter(date_added <= payment_date), x.sale %>% filter(transaction_status == 'CREATED'), by = c('phone' = 'mobile_no'))

  afterSalesCalls <- left_join(new %>% filter(date_added > payment_date), x.sale %>% filter(transaction_status == 'PAYMENT_DONE'), by = c('phone' = 'mobile_no'))

  medplusCalls <- rbind(saleAttemptCalls,afterSalesCalls)

  bulla <- medplusCalls
  # bulla

 } else if(length(which(x.sale$transaction_status == 'PAYMENT_DONE')) == 0) {

  saleAttemptCalls <- left_join(new , x.sale , by = c('phone' = 'mobile_no'))

  bulla <- saleAttemptCalls
  # bulla
} 

} else if (ncol(x.disposition) == 0){
tbr <- left_join(x.log, x.sale, by = c('phone' = 'mobile_no'))
bulla <- tbr %>% select(-transaction_id)
# bulla
}

# return(bulla)


}
```

When the if clause where *ncol(x.disposition) != 0* is evaluated, the function returns a data frame as expected. However in cases where the else clause is true, where *ncol(x.disposition) == 0* is TRUE, the function does not return anything.

I tried explicitly returning *bulla* in the end (commented out in the code) but that does not solve anything either.
I'm sure I am making only a petty mistake somewhere but can't figure out where.

Comment: What does the function `column.checker` do? What does d_f contain?

Comment: column.checker adds columns to x.disposition that should have been there but are missing. d_f is a list of 3 data frames - log, sales and disposition.

Comment: Could you include the result of `head(d_f)` in the question?

Comment: I'm asking because whatever `column.checker(x.disposition)` does, it's returning an empty data frame

Comment: you're right! i moved the column checker line inside the if clause, and it works!

Comment: but since x.disposition was empty to begin with, why should it matter?

Comment: If it works when moving `x.disposition <- column.checker(x.disposition)` inside the first `if` clause, it means that `column.checker` is never returning an empty data frame. (I was wrong on my previous comment, I meant that column.checker is not returning an empty data frame)